# Rotate a SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've written a SQL query that returns the following table, which has 3 columns. Each value is a percentage.

**Column-A Column-B Column-C**

**.1       .6       .3**

How would I rotate this table so that I have two columns and three rows: one column for name and the second column for value? I would want the result to look like

**Column-A .1**

**Column-B .6**

**Column-C .3**

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT percent(SUM (CASE WHEN fups.status = 'complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    COUNT(fups.*)) AS "Column A",
    percent(SUM (CASE WHEN fups.status = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    COUNT(fups.*)) AS "Column B",
    percent(SUM (CASE WHEN fups.status = 'dismissed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    COUNT(fups.*)) AS "Column C"
FROM ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM tasks
    WHERE task_type = 'new'
) fups
```

Comment: that's a display problem. nothing to do with sql.

Comment: Let's see the query you use

Comment: Does each row have a row identifier? If so, what is it? Show your attempt, even if it doesn't work

Comment: Tagging your question with two RDBMSs creates ambiguity.

Comment: Added my query to the post

Comment: @DanBracuk The frequency with which posts are tagged both MySQL and SQL-Server leads me to assume these are cases of MySQL users who think they need to specify that they are using SQL on a server.

Comment: It could also be people who own sql-server software.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case to generate the name part, then group by it and use count:

```
SELECT
    CASE status
        WHEN 'complete' THEN 'Column A'
        WHEN 'open' THEN 'Column B'
        WHEN 'dismissed' THEN 'Column C'
    END name,
    percent(COUNT(*), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks
        WHERE task_type = 'new'
        AND status IN ('completed', 'open', 'dismissed')) "percent"
FROM tasks
WHERE task_type = 'new'
AND status IN ('completed', 'open', 'dismissed')
GROUP BY CASE status
        WHEN 'complete' THEN 'Column A'
        WHEN 'open' THEN 'Column B'
        WHEN 'dismissed' THEN 'Column C'
    END
```

Although why you wouldn't simply use the value of the status column as-is escapes me.

Also, if you could indicate which exact database you're using, there are more efficient ways of coding this.